# Lots of kernel related errors, Help please

Tags: 16.04, kernel, mumble

I'm running 16.04 Headless on my server, (AMD GPU drivers are installed because I had a GPUrunning at one point) and I'm getting a ton of kernel errors, and I have no idea what is causing them:

```
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
mumble-server is already the newest version (1.2.12-1ubuntu1).
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libglu1-mesa libxatracker2 linux-headers-4.4.0-62
  linux-headers-4.4.0-62-generic linux-headers-4.8.0-36
  linux-headers-4.8.0-36-generic linux-headers-4.8.0-41
  linux-headers-4.8.0-41-generic linux-image-4.8.0-36-generic
  linux-image-4.8.0-41-generic linux-image-extra-4.8.0-36-generic
  linux-image-extra-4.8.0-41-generic x11-apps x11-session-utils xbitmaps
  xfonts-scalable xinit xinput
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
9 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Setting up initramfs-tools (0.122ubuntu8.8) ...
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Setting up linux-image-4.8.0-46-generic (4.8.0-46.49~16.04.1) ...
Running depmod.
update-initramfs: deferring update (hook will be called later)
The link /initrd.img is a dangling linkto /boot/initrd.img-4.8.0-45-generic
Examining /etc/kernel/postinst.d.
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 4.8.0-46-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.8.0-46-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms 4.8.0-46-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.8.0-46-generic
ERROR: Cannot create report: [Errno 17] File exists: '/var/crash/amdgpu-pro-dkms.0.crash'
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 4.8.0-46-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu-pro/16.40-348864/build/make.log for more information.
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 4.8.0-46-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.8.0-46-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.8.0-46-generic
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/kbl_dmc_ver1_01.bin for module i915
W: mdadm: /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf defines no arrays.

gzip: stdout: No space left on device
E: mkinitramfs failure find 141 cpio 141 gzip 1
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-4.8.0-46-generic with 1.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools exited with return code 1
Failed to process /etc/kernel/postinst.d at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-4.8.0-46-generic.postinst line 1052.
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-4.8.0-46-generic (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-extra-4.8.0-46-generic:
 linux-image-extra-4.8.0-46-generic depends on linux-image-4.8.0-46-generic; however:
  Package linux-image-4.8.0-46-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-4.8.0-46-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-generic-hwe-16.04:
 linux-image-generic-hwe-16.04 depends on linux-image-4.8.0-46-generic; however:
  Package linux-image-4.8.0-46-generic is not configured yet.
 linux-image-generic-hwe-16.04 depends on linux-image-extra-4.8.0-46-generic; however:
  Package linux-image-extra-4.8.0-46-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-image-generic-hwe-16.04 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-generic-hwe-16.04:
 linux-generic-hwe-16.04 depends on linux-image-generic-hwe-16.04 (= 4.8.0.46.18); however:
  Package linux-image-generic-hwe-16.04 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-generic-hwe-16.04 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up linux-image-4.8.0-41-generic (4.8.0-41.44~16.04.1) ...
Running depmod.
update-initramfs: deferring update (hook will be called later)
The link /initrd.img is a dangling linkto /boot/initrd.img-4.8.0-46-generic
Examining /etc/kernel/postinst.d.
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 4.8.0-41-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.8.0-41-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms 4.8.0-41-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.8.0-41-generic
ERROR: Cannot create report: [Errno 17] File exists: '/var/crash/amdgpu-pro-dkms.0.crash'
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 4.8.0-41-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu-pro/16.40-348864/build/make.log for more information.
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 4.8.0-41-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.8.0-41-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.8.0-41-generic
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/kbl_dmc_ver1_01.bin for module i915
W: mdadm: /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf defines no arrays.

gzip: stdout: No space left on device
E: mkinitramfs failure find 141 cpio 141 gzip 1
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-4.8.0-41-generic with 1.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools exited with return code 1
Failed to process /etc/kernel/postinst.d at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-4.8.0-41-generic.postinst line 1052.
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-4.8.0-41-generic (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
Setting up linux-image-4.8.0-45-generic (4.8.0-45.48~16.04.1) ...
Running depmod.
update-initramfs: deferring update (hook will be called later)
The link /initrd.img is a dangling linkto /boot/initrd.img-4.8.0-41-generic
Examining /etc/kernel/postinst.d.
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 4.8.0-45-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.8.0-45-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms 4.8.0-45-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.8.0-45-generic
ERROR: Cannot create report: [Errno 17] File exists: '/var/crash/amdgpu-pro-dkms.0.crash'
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 4.8.0-45-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu-pro/16.40-348864/build/make.log for more information.
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 4.8.0-45-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.8.0-45-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.8.0-45-generic
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/kbl_dmc_ver1_01.bin for module i915
W: mdadm: /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf defines no arrays.

gzip: stdout: No space left on device
E: mkinitramfs failure find 141 cpio 141 gzip 1
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-4.8.0-45-generic with 1.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools exited with return code 1
Failed to process /etc/kernel/postinst.d at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-4.8.0-45-generic.postinst line 1052.
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-4.8.0-45-generic (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-extra-4.8.0-41-generic:
 linux-image-extra-4.8.0-41-generic depends on linux-image-4.8.0-41-generic; however:
  Package linux-image-4.8.0-41-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-4.8.0-41-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-extra-4.8.0-45-generic:
 linux-image-extra-4.8.0-45-generic depends on linux-image-4.8.0-45-generic; however:
  Package linux-image-4.8.0-45-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-4.8.0-45-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.122ubuntu8.8) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.8.0-39-generic
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/kbl_dmc_ver1_01.bin for module i915
W: mdadm: /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf defines no arrays.

gzip: stdout: No space left on device
E: mkinitramfs failure find 141 cpio 141 gzip 1
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-4.8.0-39-generic with 1.
dpkg: error processing package initramfs-tools (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-4.8.0-46-generic
 linux-image-extra-4.8.0-46-generic
 linux-image-generic-hwe-16.04
 linux-generic-hwe-16.04
 linux-image-4.8.0-41-generic
 linux-image-4.8.0-45-generic
 linux-image-extra-4.8.0-41-generic
 linux-image-extra-4.8.0-45-generic
 initramfs-tools

No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                          No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                    No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                  No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                                              No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                            No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                          No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                        E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

If anyone could help me fix these, that would really be awesome of you. Thanks.

Also, I'm trying to do `apt-get install mumble-server`, and it gives me that output.

Comment: It says "no space left on device", so I would guess your `/boot` is full.

Comment: what is the result of `df -h`?